# Fatal errors while building Python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python

I'm building Python 3.9.2 on a raspberry pi.

Doing a simple build with `./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install` succeeds, but my Python project, which runs fine with the Python installed from the `apt` repos, won't run with this compiled Python. It throws a whole whack of errors. Simpler code runs fine though.

Using `python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('CONFIG_ARGS'))"`, I can tell which args the Python from the `apt` repos was using, so I tried to use them as well. My configure line ended up being this:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --enable-ipv6 --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --with-dbmliborder=bdb:gdbm --with-computed-gotos --with-ensurepip=install --with-system-expat --with-system-libmpdec --with-system-ffi CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc "CFLAGS=-g   -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security " "LDFLAGS= -Wl,-z,relro" "CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2"
```

I'm not entirely sure what all of them mean, but the distribution maintainers thought they were important enough to be included, so that's good enough for me.

The problem I ran into is on the last step. When I'm done compiling, and I run `sudo make altinstall`, I get some errors:

```
/usr/local/src/Python-3.9.2/Modules/pyexpat.c:6:10: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory
...
/usr/local/src/Python-3.9.2/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c:32:10: fatal error: mpdecimal.h: No such file or directory
```

The thing is, both of these files exist here:

```
/usr/local/src/Python-3.9.2/Modules/expat/expat.h
/usr/local/src/Python-3.9.2/Modules/_decimal/libmpdec/mpdecimal.h
```

Since the code that I'm compiling is in `/usr/local/src/Python-3.9.2`, you'd think it would be able to find the files in its own build directory.

Am I doing something wrong?